# Parallel run and wait for pocesses from subshell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, pid

Hi all/ I'm trying to make something like **parallel** tool for shell simply because the functionality of **parallel** is not enough for my task. The reason is that I need to run different versions of compiler.
Imagine that I need to compile 12 programs with different compilers, but I can run only 4 of them simultaneously (otherwise PC runs out of memory and crashes :). I also want to be able to observe what's going on with each compile, therefore I execute every compile in new window.
Just to make it easier here I'll replace compiler that I run with small script that waits and returns it's process id ***sleep.sh***:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30 
echo $$
```

So the main script should look like ***parallel_run.sh*** :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..11}; do
  xfce4-terminal -H -e "./sleep.sh" &
  pids[$i]=$!
  pstree -p $pids
  if (( $i % 4 == 0 ))
  then
    for pid in ${pids[*]}; do 
      wait $pid
    done
  fi
done
```

The problem is that with $! I get pid of xfce4-terminal and not the program it executes. So if I look at **ptree** of 1st iteration I can see output from main script:

```
xfce4-terminal(31666)----{xfce4-terminal}(31668)
                      |--{xfce4-terminal}(31669)
```

and **sleep.sh** says that it had ***pid = 30876*** at that time. Thus wait doesn't work at all in this case.

Q: How to get right PID of compiler that runs in subshell?
Maybe there is the other way to solve task like this?

Comment: Why are you running the processes in their own terminal? If you really want to do this, wrap the invocation of the compiler into a small shell script, which retrieves the PID, and stores it in some file. Your `parallel_run.sh` can then retrieve the PID to monitor from the file. Alternatively, ensure that the terminal is closed (i.e. terminates), after the compiler is done. In this case, waiting for the terminal is the right choice anyway.

Comment: I want to run processes in different terminals just to not mess up the output from all of them...and also to fallow the proceess.
Saving PID into file from child processt should work. But I would rather wait until terminal is closed as this solution looks simpler. Nevertheless I can't get PID of running terminal..It looks like xfce4-terminal makes process called sleep.sh and somehow xfce4-terminal disappears afterwards. From ptree that I shared you can see that 31666 makes 31668 and 31669, but they appears just for a moment and there is only sleep.sh process for the rest of the sleep time.

Comment: If you only want to get their output out of the way, run them with `nohup` or save the output manually in a file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to trace PID from parent to child if you invoke process in new xfce4-terminal as terminal process dies right after it executed given command. So I came to the solution which is not perfect, but acceptable in my situation. I run and put compiler's processes in background and redirect output to .log file. Then I run **tail** on these logfiles and I kill all tails which belongs to current $USER when compilers from current batch are done, then I run the other batch.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..8}; do
  ./sleep.sh > ./process_$i.log &
  prcid=$!
  xfce4-terminal -e "tail -f ./process_$i.log" &
  pids[$i]=$prcid
  if (( $i % 4 == 0 ))
  then
    for pid in ${pids[*]}; do 
      wait $pid
    done
  killall -u $USER tail
  fi
done
```

Hopefully there will be no other **tails** running at that time :)